# AngularJS checkbox odd behavior

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

some friends and I are working on a project. This is the second project in which I am working with AngularJS, were currently using version 1.2.3.

Despite that I sometimes find some of its behavior odd, and don't understand why something is happening.

So the situation is this... I have in my cshtml file the followig:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
         <input name="somecheckbox" type="checkbox" ng-click="click()" ng-model="displayRegardlessOfSomething" />
         <label>Display regardless of something</label>
    </label>
</div>

<h1>{{displayRegardlessOfSomething}}</h1>
```

In my javascript file I have the following code inside a directive:

At the very beginning:

```
$scope.displayRegardlessOfSomething = true;
```

And I have the following:

```
$scope.click = function () {
    console.log($scope.displayRegardlessOfSomething)
}
```

And whenever I check or uncheck the checkbox I always get **true**... However, the peculiar part is that the content inside the **`<h1></h1>`** tags changes.... So, it's like I am changing the value of a variable on the html layer, but not on the JavaScript layer...

Why is this happening?

I have solved the problem by using $parent.displayRegardlessOfSomething but I don't understand why that fixed the problem... what caused the problem in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried what you did in the fiddle and it works fine for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/nicolasmoise/X9KYU/1/

The fact that it works for you when you used `$parent` makes me think a parent controller is at fault here. Maybe you have two variables with the same names?

P.S. : remember that in Javascript, primitives are passed by value and objects are passed by reference. This is the cause of many mistakes for Angular developers. See this fiddle where I illustrate my point.

with primitives: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolasmoise/X9KYU/

with objects: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolasmoise/X9KYU/2/

Comment: yes I understand that it works fine for you, it also works fine in the angular documentation.
I didn't think it was relevant in my situation that something is being passed by reference or by value... so perhaps, somewhere I have another $scope in my application.... However, I have only one directive with one controller that uses the named variable :/

Comment: Right so as me and @null are both trying to say is that the problem is most likely in one of your parent controllers (which we don't have). So try to use objects, not primitives, in other words, "have a dot in your ng-model"

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. However, I still don't quite understand where in my code the conflict could be manifesting :/
But I will take your advice and use objects :)

Comment: Just to be clear, the problem may not have been with a parent CONTROLLER necessarily, but with a parent SCOPE.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're pretty sure everything is living in the same scope, which is almost never, you should **always have a dot somewhere in your ng-model expression**.

```
myApp.controller('MyController2', function($scope) {

  $scope.model = { displayRegardlessOfSomething: true };

  $scope.click = function() {
    console.log($scope.model.displayRegardlessOfSomething);
  };
});

<input type="checkbox" 
       ng-click="click()" 
       ng-model="model.displayRegardlessOfSomething" />
```

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/veuQWtkfh1JYvgW0iKTv?p=preview) for details for live demo.